# Custom protocol for Docusaurus

Tags: electron, docusaurus

We want to serve a Docusaurus-build with Electron.

For this we are using a custom protocol that just serves the files to the Electron-Browser.

The Problem is, the Javascript that is running in the static-html build of the Docusaurus app just wont accept the url (at least that is what we think)

If we serve "doc://doc/docs/intro/index.html" it pops up for a second and afterwards the "Page Not Found"-page is shown - because the javascript does that.

Our url is "doc://doc" and our baseUrl is "/" and we can not figure out how to stop the Javascript from chaning the currently loaded page to the Page not found one.

(We disabled the Javascript and if it is disabled that error does not appear)

Comment: Hi, I also want to add a Docusaurus to my Electron app, I tried to load the docs using `win.loadURL(new URL('../../docs/build/index.html', 'file://' + __dirname).toString())` and , but it's not working, it says the baseUrl is not correct. How do you load the docs in Electron without a server?

Comment: @Chi first you need to build the Docusaurus "app" and then you need to tell electron that it should include those files in the build with extrafiles (at least thats how we did it) and then you should be able to access the files... if not feel free to text me back and I'll look into it again (i was nat the lead dev on this when we did it :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was Electron...

You have to give the custom protocol privledge with this:

```
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
  {
    scheme: 'doc',
    privileges: { secure: true, standard: true },
  },
]);
```

So it has actually nothing to do with Docusaurus.